# How to get the logged in user details in hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I have an endpoint `/api/account` where I am creating the details of an account but not passing user details anywhere just using the `accesstoken` to authorise the user using `hapi-auth-bearer-simple`. Now I have a field called creator where I want to auto-populate the logged in user details like id and the name.

Could anyone suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The credentials you passed via the auth scheme are available via `request.auth.credentials`